# Error "acme: Could not determine solvers" when trying to get a LetsEncrpyt cert

Tags: ssl, traefik

I have a domain on a webhost, and a subdomain on Digital Ocean. I'm attempting to register a LetsEncrypt SSL cert using an acme config in the traefik.toml.

```
[acme]
email = "myemail@pirion.net"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
```

The logs are providing the following error:

```
time="2018-01-12T03:25:37Z" level=debug msg="LoadCertificateForDomains [endpoint.pirion.net]..." 
time="2018-01-12T03:25:37Z" level=debug msg="Look for provided certificate to validate [endpoint.pirion.net]..." 
time="2018-01-12T03:25:37Z" level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains [endpoint.pirion.net], get ACME certificate." 
time="2018-01-12T03:25:37Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [endpoint.pirion.net]..." 
time="2018-01-12T03:25:37Z" level=error msg="map[endpoint.pirion.net:[endpoint.pirion.net] acme: Could not determine solvers]" 
time="2018-01-12T03:25:37Z" level=error msg="Error getting ACME certificates [endpoint.pirion.net] : Cannot obtain certificates map[endpoint.pirion.net:[endpoint.pirion.net] acme: Could not determine solvers]+v"
```

I'm unable to find much about what the solvers are. Is there something I need to add to my setup?

Comment: Looks like it could be related to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2018-01-11-update-regarding-acme-tls-sni-and-shared-hosting-infrastructure/50188 according to slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to a Let's Encrypt issue:

- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2018-01-09-issue-with-tls-sni-01-and-shared-hosting-infrastructure/49996
- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2018-01-11-update-regarding-acme-tls-sni-and-shared-hosting-infrastructure/50188

You can use the DNS challenge instead. https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#dnsprovider

Comment: It says they are not going to re-enable it. How do we use `HTTP-01` verification? DNS verification does not work when I try, it always times out.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that to fix this error, you need to specify that you are using [http challenge](http://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/acme/#acmehttpchallenge):

```
[acme]
# ...
entryPoint = "https"
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

As of the moment of writing this was fixed [fairly recently](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2701), so you might need a fresher version (1.5) of traefik, than you are using now.

Answer (score 0):

It could sound out of the scope
For me I use Lego. What solved the issue with me is to use the parameter
`--dns "manual"`
Which will prompt some tasks to do ( to insert `txt` records at your dns provider )
I think it is easier to do it manually than tell the service which dns provider you use.
I think you could do sth similar at your issue.